# Running python scripts in minimal ubuntu environment

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, operating-system, qemu

I am running a Gem5 Full system simulation , while mounting the image on gem5 I bypass the systemd services using the command line argument --kernel-init=/bin/sh, I do this to reduce the mount time for system boot on gem5 simulator , however ,once I get to the terminal I am unable to run any packages like numpy and scripts related to python I keep getting following error

```
/home/ubuntu/benchmark/# python execute.py
[    0.461255] random: python: uninitialized urandom read (24 bytes read)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/ubuntu/benchmark/execute.py", line 10, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'
```

I should also mention i created this disk image using qemu where I have two versions of python on the image , once I mounted my benchmarks and installed necessary packages on qemu I mounted the image on gem5 , I would like to know what needs to be done to execute image in this minimal environment

even if I do python - c import numpy while running on the simulator it still says numpy not found

File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'numpy'

Comment: Did you try `pip install numpy` ?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure numpy is installed;
Try `pip install numpy` or check [numpy site](https://numpy.org/install/) to see how to install.

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged for [these reasons](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259/236527). Please edit your answer to include the context, or wait until you have enough rep to comment. Thanks